# Creating An If Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

My client wants to use Google Sheets instead of Excel. I could quickly write the code in VBA but am hitting a brick wall with Google Sheets.

H5 contains a drop-down list. I want the values in D5, D6, D7 and D8 to equal the value in H5 BUT only if a value has been selected in H5.

I have built my code based on similar examples I have seen on this website. I tried to debug my code but I didn't find the debugging tools in Google Sheets to be nearly as effective as in VBA.

```
function PercentageIncreases1() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

   var cell1 = ("H5");
   var cell2 = ("H6");
   var cell3 = ("H7");
   var cell4 = ("H8");

    if (cell1 > 0) {
  spreadsheet.getRange('D5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=H5');
  spreadsheet.getRange('D6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=H5');
  spreadsheet.getRange('D7').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=H5');
  spreadsheet.getRange('D8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=H5');
    }



};
```

If the value in H5 is 10, then I expect the values in D5, D6, D7, D8 to also be 10.

At the moment the values in D5, D6, D7 and D8 are not being updated.

Comment: and if H5 isnt 10 do you want D5 to be anything else or just blank? coz you could use an arrayformula

Answer (score 0):

1. Google Sheets use Google Apps Script for macros.
2. Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript
3. To create an if statement use JavaScript's [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0):

Try this if this is what you are looking for,

```
function PercentageIncreases1() 
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell1 = spreadsheet.getRange("H5").getValues();
  var cell2= spreadsheet.getRange("H6").getValues();
  var cell3= spreadsheet.getRange("H7").getValues();
  var cell4= spreadsheet.getRange("H8").getValues();
  if (cell1[0][0] > 0) 
  {
    if(cell1[0][0] == 10)
    {
      spreadsheet.getRange("D5").setValue(cell1[0][0]);
      spreadsheet.getRange("D6").setValue(cell1[0][0]);
      spreadsheet.getRange("D7").setValue(cell1[0][0]);
      spreadsheet.getRange("D8").setValue(cell1[0][0]);
    }
    else
    {

    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();

  if (selection != "")
    ss.getRange("D5:D8").setValue(selection);
}
```

I created a drop-down menu in `A1` with a few number values to choose from. the code will check the selection, and if it's not empty, it will populate `D5:D8` with the selected number. The function will run whenever the sheet gets edited.

since you're starting with Apps Script, I suggest you take a look at the [SpreadsheetApp documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) as well as [this introduction of App Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)